# YQL Finance API URL Construction

Tags: php, json, url, yql

I'm currently trying to request some market quotes from the Yahoo Finance API (YQL) for a project I'm working on and I'm having a little trouble with building the query URL.

If I go to the YQL console and request quotes for Microsoft it returns me the following URL:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

If I throw this directly into my code and run my query with this URL, it works fine and I can grab what data I want. However I want to be able to construct my own query url so that I can choose which stocks I want to grab the information for without having to copy the link from the YQL console.

Now when I try to build my own URL (following the YQL examples on the site) I run into a problem; my url doesn't encode itself in the same way the console does and I can't get any information back.

Here's the code I'm using to build my own URL:

```
$yql_base_url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
$yql_query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in ('MSFT')";
$yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . urlencode($yql_query);
$yql_query_url .= "&format=json&diagnostics=true";
$yql_query_url .= "&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";
```

Now when I print this URL out alongside the one copied from the YQL console, it's easy to see they aren't the same at all which is most likely why it isn't working.

For comparison,
my URL:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+%2A+from+yahoo.finance.quote+where+symbol+in+%28%27MSFT%27%29&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

YQL Console URL:

```
    https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

Can anybody who has used this before, or can see any mistakes I might be making offer some help, it would be greatly appreciated.

YQL Tutorial I was following:
https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_php

Answer (score 0):

you can try `rawurlencode` instead. However the url you posted works just fine in my browser.